# Android Switching Activities Black Screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to start another activity in my main activity using this method:

```
 public void switchToRead(){// Switches to the reading view which displays the text that the tts engine reads off.
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReadOut.class);
    intent.putExtra("response", res);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This starts the following class:

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReadOut extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnClickListener {


    boolean paused = false;
    String leftToRead = null;
    String res = null;
    TextToSpeech tts;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {  
        System.out.println("Pre-execute");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read_out);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        res = intent.getExtras().getString("response");
        TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textv.setText(res);
        textv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
        textv.setHeight((int)(display.getHeight()*0.76));
        System.out.println("START");
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    public String speakFull(String text){
        System.out.println("Speaking: " + text);
        System.out.println("Speaking");
        String[] sentences = text.split("\n|\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\."); // Regex that splits the body of text into the sentences of that body which are stored in a String array.
        for(int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++){
            if(!tts.isSpeaking() && !paused){
                System.out.println("Speaking: " + i);
                tts.speak(sentences[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }else if(paused){
                System.out.println("Paused");
                String paused = "";
                int k = 0;
                if(i != 0){
                    k = i-1;
                }
                leftToRead = null;
                for(int j = k; j < sentences.length; j++){
                    leftToRead += sentences[j];
                }
                return leftToRead;
            }else{
                i--;
                System.out.println("Sleeping");
                System.out.println("Speaking : " + tts.isSpeaking());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            if(i == sentences.length - 1){
                return "Message 001: Complete";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int arg0) {
            System.out.println("speakFull");
            leftToRead = speakFull(res);

    }

    public void clickPause(View v){
        if(paused){
            paused = false;
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setText("Play");
        }else{
            paused = true;
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setText("Pause");
            if(leftToRead == null){
                leftToRead = speakFull(res);
            }else{
                leftToRead = speakFull(leftToRead);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

After the ReadOut class is started one of a couple things can happen,
either the screen turns black, the text to speech begins reading, and the app is telling me it's not responding, OR it shows me the view for ReadOut, reads in text to speech, and then tells me it's not responding.
I'm really confused as to why this is happening, and any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to debug this code?i think that error can come from this part starting from TextView texttv to tts = new TextToSpeech

Comment: Okay, I moved tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this); to the first line of the speakFull method, now it switches views fine, but it doesn't read the text.

Comment: hmm try to add part part to the code like remove everything like display and tts and keep textview etc until you get the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about using TTS but I can tell you that this line is probably causing a problem

```
 Thread.sleep(1000);
```

It appears you are calling it on the `UI Thread` which isn't a good idea. You need to use a background `Thread` and update it with something like `runOnUiThread()` or `AsyncTask` or you could use a `Handler`.